# Как сделать постоянно активную ссылку?

Tags: html, css

Суть в том, как сделать, чтоб сколько ни тыкал на ссылку, она была активная. )) Помогите, плс.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как написано ранее, но  если для конкретной ссылки - не для всех, то конкретный стиль  именно для этой ссылки, в CSS:

```
a.mystyle {color:#...;}
```

в `<body>`

```
<a href ="...." class="mystyle">нужный Вам цвет!</a>
```

Уточнение:

```
a.mystyle {color: #fff;}
a:hover.mystyle {color: #F00;}
a:visited.mystyle {color: #F0F;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Написать один стиль для обычной и посещенной:

```
a:link, a:visited{
 color: #0000ff;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но как-то делают через onclick.

Answer (score 1):

Можно для всех ссылок задать цвет

```
a{color: blue; }
```